# In a calendar app, should we find time zone on client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, npm, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am trying to build a small event/calendar React app. The server side provides an API like the following

```
POST /events

{
   organizer: foo@example.com,
   time_slot: {
      start: starttime, // my intent is 6:00pm local time
      end: endtime      // my intent is 9:00pm local time 
   }
}
```

The more I think of this, the more I feel the client side need to understand its local time zone, and make the `starttime` and `endtime` of the above request payload UTC format. However, I want the user to fill in local time (nobody would input UTC at the user interface level). Therefore, there must be some kind of local time to UTC conversation on the client side.

I have two questions here:

1. is there an npm package for client side to reliably get its local time zone? so that it can reliably convert local time to UTC?
2. Is the above methodology (i.e., relying on client side to do the conversation) the correct one or not? Does commercial calendar, such as Google Calendar, achieve this kind of solution in the above methodology?

Comment: The Google Calendar API allows you to retrieve the user's timezone and locale, see [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings).

Comment: All calendar applications should have the functionality to convert to client side timezone from the timezones that may be in the ics file.  Test for yourself:  Subscribe or import an ics file with different timezone into a test calendar.  Google calendar even allows one to have different calendars with different timezones.